# WrapPanel ItemsControl Referring to Individual Items from Original Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, event-handling, itemscontrol

I am making a real estate management program and on the main page I have all of the properties listed something like this in a `WrapPanel`:

[image: Main Panel with Properties]

Now, even though each of the properties is exactly the same, that is only for demonstration and testing with multiple properties. Each of the properties is a different `Property` object inside of an ObservableCollection Property (sorry for the confusion of names) as shown by my c# code below:

```
public ObservableCollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }

// ...

Property defaultProperty = new Property(/*Lots of Stuff*/);
properties.Add(defaultProperty);
properties.Add(defaultProperty);
properties.Add(defaultProperty);
properties.Add(defaultProperty);
properties.Add(defaultProperty);
Properties = properties;
```

These Properties (part of the Properties property (sorry again)) are then shown through an itemscontrol which is shown below:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="wPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel x:Name="PropertyPanel" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border  Margin="5,5,5,5" BorderBrush="Red"  BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid MinWidth="350" MouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    // Column and Row Definitions
                    // ...
                    // Three other corners of the grid
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,5,5,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="IssuesPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown" > // <-- This is the part I'm trying to get to work
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IssuesNum}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" Issues " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="/VentureVisions;component/warning.png" DecodePixelWidth="18" />
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                   </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I took out the parts that didn't matter to this. I'm trying to open up a window about the issues of the property when the user clicks on the issues panel in the bottom right. I've got an event set up, but I need to be able to get the Property object to get the Issues collection from it to display in the window. I hope this makes sense. Comment if now. But how do I know how to reference the specific Property that the user is interacting with after the button click? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like this is answered using several different flavours, refer to the following topics:

1. [Binding to CurrentItem in a ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939907/binding-to-currentitem-in-a-itemscontrol)
2. [How to highlight selected item in ItemsControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069374/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-itemscontrol)

Hopefully those help.

To further aid you if you are using any level of data binding then you can simply bind the "issues" image interaction to a command on the "viewmodel", in your instance the viewmodel will be the **Property** object.

Comment: Would you happen to know of a way to do this without using mvvm terminology? I'm meaning to get into that and look at it, but I haven't used it at all in this project so far, and so... it would be nice if I could keep it the way it is.

Comment: I looked around a bit more, and ended up finding one of the pages that you had. It took me a while to see how it fit into my problem. But it did. Thanks.