# Creating a ViewModel for each item of ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have defined a type **Board** which containes a public property

```
ObservableCollection<Column> Columns
```

I would like to display it with use of MVVM pattern. 
I created **BoardView** and bound it to **BoardViewModel**. BoardViewModel exposes public property **Board** of type Board.
BoardView contains a control ItemsControl which sets ItemsSource={Binding Board.Columns}.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Board.Columns}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="2" Margin="10" BorderBrush="#9f9f9f" Width="250">
            <v:BoardColumnView Background="#e3e3e3" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

**BoardColumnView** should show properties of **Column** type and this works good.
My problem is that I want to create a ViewModel for BoardColumn, and instead of showing only properties of Column type I want to show **BoardColumnViewModel** which would have defined inside a **Column** property.
How can I achieve that?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Very unclear. Why cannot you just define BoardColumnViewModel inside of Column class as you wrote at the end of your question?

Comment: Hi, sorry for unclear description, but I did my best.
I cannot use Column to hold ColumnBoardViewModel, since it is database entity. I just wonder If I can bind BoardColumnView.xaml.DataContext to BoardColumnViewModel and in ItemsControl just bind BoardColumnViewModel.Column to ItemsControl.CurrentItem.

Comment: Perhaps it could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939907/binding-to-currentitem-in-a-itemscontrol

Comment: Hi, it helped and led me to few interesting threads on Stackoverflow. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply define a `Columns` property in your `BoardViewModel` that would contain a collection of `BoardColumnViewModel`. Something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<BoardColumnViewModel> Columns { get; private set; }
```

You will need to initialize this property somewhere in `BoardViewModel`, for example:

```
public BoardViewModel(...)
{
     ...
     Columns = new ObservableCollection<BoardColumnViewModel>(Board.Columns.Select(c => new BoardColumnViewModel(c)));
}
```

And then bind to that property, instead of `Board.Columns`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="2" Margin="10" BorderBrush="#9f9f9f" Width="250">
                <v:BoardColumnView Background="#e3e3e3" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As a general principle in MVVM is that it is not recommended to bind directly to a model. Instead you should always try to bind to a view model. This is why you have the problem you've described - because you bind to a public property `Board`, which is your model.

Comment: Hi, I thought about such solution, but I had concerns whether it's good or bad solution. You convinced me that this is the way to go. Thanks that you mentioned  that binding to Model directly is not recommended, I was not aware of this. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding is `BoardColumnView` an own UserControl?

If so just set the DataContext of this UserControl with `this.DataContext = new BoardColumnViewModel();` in code behind or use XAML equivalent. Then create in your `BoardViewModel` an `ObserveableCollection<>` which holds multiple Instances of `BoardColumnView` and set the `ItemSource` to this collection. In your `BoardColumnView` XAML define your Layout, Bindings, etc. which are displayed in `BoardView`.

So every time you add a `BoardColumnView` to the ItemsSource, which is bound to the collection, a new instance of `BoardColumnViewModel` is getting created.

...That is my understanding of your Problem, but I might be completely wrong :).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Do I understand your answer correctly, you wrote that in body of BoardViewModel I should have a collection of BoardColumnView (or do you meant BoardColumnViewModel)? Because, having the connection to BoardColumnView in ViewModel violates the whole idea of MVVM. If this is just an error then I think it's very good solution. thank you a lot.

Comment: Yeah little mistake on my side. Pavlos answer is the way to go!